# Using "nevertheless" after "while"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality, conjunctions

Is the following use of "nevertheless" correct:

> While this book is outside my subject area, nevertheless, it was
>   useful to me.

Comment: Yeh, only "While this book is outside my subject area it, nevertheless, was useful to me."

Answer (score -2):

What you wrote is intelligible but the following word order is more natural:

```
While this book is outside my subject area, it was nevertheless useful to me.
```

Comment: Why the downvote?   Does a native speaker disagree that this is the more natural word order?  Or that the quote in the question is intelligible?

Comment: I think that BadZen's complaint is legitimate. I feel that down-voters should identify themselves and explain why. Otherwise, the person answering is none the wiser. Nor are other readers.